# positioning doesn't work with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building an "autofill" function. When the user types something in an input field and the system finds this string in the database it should display the string into the input field in grey, similar to what google used to/still have/has.

Therefore I built two input fields, one that's clearly visible:

html:

```
<input id="email_input" type="text">
<input id="autofill" type="text">
```

css:

```
#email_input{
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Then I position the `autofill` input via JS exactly where `email_input` is.

```
function positionAutocompleteInput(){
  var top = $('#email_input').position().top;
  var left = $('#email_input').position().left;
  $('#autofill').css({'top':top});
  $('#autofill').css({'left':left});
}
positionAutoFillInput();
```

The actual autfill I do like this:

```
function autofill(context){
  var input = $('#email_input').val();
  var replacement = context[0].email;
  replacement = replacement.slice(input.length);
  var display = input + replacement;
  $('#autofill').val(display)
}
```

I tried calling `positionAutoFillInput();` onInput, so that it gets repositioned with each input. If I look at the positions of both input fields in the console, they both have the same positions.

Both input fields have the same font-size and font-family.

For some reason it still looks off:

[image]

Anyone know an answer?

Comment: I think this is because <input type="text"> indents the text a little, and getting the left and top values won't specifically get you the position where the text starts.

Comment: Did you forget to clear off the last value?

Comment: Why not just do something with pure css, I don't get the value to position something with js? A question, are you trying to get a dropdown with emails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you just position them with CSS like this? This way it requires no JavaScript to position it.

```css
#autofill, #email_input {
  font-size: 20px;
}

#autofill {
  position: absolute;
  color: #CCCCCC;
}

#email_input {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<h1>Test</h1>
<div>
  <input id="autofill" type="text" value="1234567890">
  <input id="email_input" type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: If you disable the `autofill` input, users cannot accidentally tab into it. And I guess they don't need to modify the value themselves.